# How to setup Google Calendar Java App

Tags: java, jar, classpath, google-calendar-api

I'm following along with the step-by-step [configuration instructions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate) by Google, but for some reason I can't find a few packages they're requiring me to import. The packages which my app is unable to find are (or the lines my IDE is complaining about):

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl;
```

I can't seem to find the jars which hold these. My classpath contains:

```
//The Google Calendar Client API:
google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev16-1.8.0-beta.jar

//And of course the Google API Core:
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-api-client-android-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-android-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-api-client-android2-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-android2-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-api-client-appengine-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-java6-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-http-client-android-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-http-client-android2-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android2-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-http-client-android3-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android3-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-http-client-appengine-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-http-client-jackson-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-jackson-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-http-client-jackson2-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar.properties
google-oauth-client-appengine-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-java6-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-jetty-1.11.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-servlet-1.11.0-beta.jar
gson-2.1.jar
gson-2.1.jar.properties
guava-11.0.1.jar
guava-11.0.1.jar.properties
httpclient-4.0.3.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
jackson-core-2.0.5.jar
jackson-core-2.0.5.jar.properties
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar.properties
jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
jetty-6.1.26.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
transaction-api-1.1.jar
xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
```

I'm not sure what it is I'm missing, but I need those libraries to continue the tutorial. If more information is necessary I'll be happy to provide it. I'm a newbie when it comes to the Google Calendar API. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I thought draft10 had been deprecated, although google hasn't seen fit to update there examples

Comment: You might like to have a look at [draft 10](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10) and [OAuth 2.0](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I think it is deprecated. Do you know of another example that uses another method?

Comment: Not having used it before, I'm not 100% sure, but you could try [Calendar API v3, 2-legged OAuth & Java](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/calendar-api-v3-2-legged-oauth-java.html), you could also look at [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of now, Google has not updated [the Java configuration source code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate). You do not need those classes, and as others in their comments pointed out, they are deprecated.

Substitute the "draft10" imports by:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
```

Then, substitute the authorization code (from comment "Step 1: Authorize -->" onwards ) by:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
            Arrays.asList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setAccessType("online")
                .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(redirectUrl).build();
System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");

System.out.println("  " + url);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String code = br.readLine();

GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code)
                .setRedirectUri(redirectUrl).execute();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential()
                .setFromTokenResponse(response);

// Create a new authorized API client
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                credential).build();
```

I had the same problem, and found [the drive sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample) to be up to date. I guessed my way through, and made it work. "Authorization Code Flow" is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Authorization_Code_Flow).